# Cobertura check fails when maven run with Cobertura report and install goals

Tags: maven, cobertura, maven-cobertura-plugin

I have Cobertura setup as following in my pom:

```
...
<build>
...
<plugins>
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${cobertura-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <formats>
            <format>html</format>
        </formats>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
        <check>
            <haltOnFailure>${testsAreRun}</haltOnFailure>
            <totalBranchRate>27</totalBranchRate>
            <totalLineRate>88</totalLineRate>
        </check>
        <instrumentation>
            <ignoreTrivial>true</ignoreTrivial>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>something/app/**/*.class</exclude>
                <exclude>something/config/**/*.class</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </instrumentation>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>clean</goal>
                <!--<goal>cobertura</goal>-->
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
...
<plugins>
...
<build>
...
```

If I run:

```
mvn clean cobertura:cobertura
```

Everything passes fine. If I run:

```
mvn clean install
```

Everything passes fine. However, if I run:

```
mvn clean cobertura:cobertura install
```

The build fails during the install saying that my code coverage is 0% i.e:

```
[ERROR] Oct 22, 2014 3:03:59 PM net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.CoverageDataFileHandler loadCoverageData
INFO: Cobertura: Loaded information on 8 classes.
Project failed check. Total branch coverage rate of 0.0% is below 27.0%
Project failed check. Total line coverage rate of 0.0% is below 88.0%

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 15.839 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-10-22T15:03:59+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 38M/469M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:2.6:check (default) on project something: Coverage check failed. See messages above. -> [Help 1]
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

When you run:

> mvn cobertura:cobertura

It just generated the reports.

when you run

> mvn install

It runs all the plugins you have set up there, including configurations you have set up which have the line and branch checks